# Updating .NET Framework on Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB

Tags: windows-10

A program I am trying to install on a device equipped with Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB requires .NET Framework 4.7. However as far as I can tell the .NET Framework version on the device is 4.6. I am unable to manually install a higher version due to error code HRESULT 0x800f081e, which supposedly means that .NET Framework is already included in the OS and is thus unable to be updated.

Is there a way to update the .NET Framework version that I am missing? Or am I stuck unable to install the program?